# How can i pass input parameter to nested object in Graphene?

Tags: python-3.x, graphene-python

I'm not sure what is the best way to pass variable inside nested type, hope someone already faced the same case and can help.

Code example is:

```
class UserType(ObjectType):
    firstname = String(required=True)

    def resolve_firstname(parent, info):
        user = get_user_by_id()
        return user.firstname


class UserResult(Union):
    class Meta:
        types = [UserType, ErrorError, ]


class Query(ObjectType):
    user = Field(
        UserResult,
        user_id=String(required=True)
    )

    async def resolve_user(parent, info, user_id):
        result = UserType()
        # or return error from Union

        return result
```

And graphQL query looks:

```
query{
  user(user_id: "uuid_here") {
    ... on UserType {
        data
    }
    ... on SomeError {
        message
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Union to provide info about returning types in schema.
I have access to *user_id* in *resolve_user*, but i need this value in *UserType*'s * resolve_firstname*. In this case i need way pass this variable.

What are ways to do so?
I can modify UserType and add user_id near *firstname = String(required=True)* and pass user_id this way - UserType(user_id=user_id). But in this case user_id will be available in schema.

Is it correct to use `__init__` method in graphene's custom type? In this case i'll be able use variable and hide it from graphql's schema.